# Point Sampling Tool Output Empty

Tags: qgis

I am trying to extract elevation values for each point in a point .shp from a DEM. Both files align and are in the same CRS - 4326. The tool runs but I receive an error message and the output file is completely empty. Does anyone have any tips on how to get a correct result?

This error message is repeated many times:

> Feature write errors: Feature creation error (OGR error: Attempt to write non-point (MULTIPOINT) geometry to point shapefile.)

[image: error message]

Comment: What software are you working in? It looks like the tool may not support multipart geometry thus, the "non-point (MULTIPOINT)" error. Try exploding your shapefile so that it is not MULTIPOINT. Also, please add a tag indicating the software that this relates to.

Comment: I am using QGIS 3.4

Comment: The multipart geometry output from the Regular Points Tool seems to be the problem I tried creating a new point dataset using Create Grid but got the same multipart output. I don't understand why a point .shp would be multipart. Is there a way to remedy this?

Answer (score 6):

That error message says that your input geometry type should be POINT, but it's actually MULTIPOINT. The solution is to convert your MULTIPOINT layer to POINT format. Use the `Multipart to singleparts` tool, which you can find in the Processing Toolbox.