# GeoPandas clip iteration stops midway through

Tags: python, clip, geopandas

I have two shapefiles that I am using for a verification processes. I am trying to clip some centroids to some buffers I made to reduce the amount of centroids. The code runs through, but with this centroid set, it clips to the first two buffers and then stops. I can clearly see that there are centroids in the other buffers. I am not quite sure why this is happening.

Any suggestions?

[image]

[Centroid shapefile](http://www.filedropper.com/centroid7)

[Buffer](http://www.filedropper.com/buffer)

```
import geopandas
import glob
import os

Centroid_path = "D:/Random/Centroid_Clip/99"
Extent_path = "E:/99/verification/99Buffer.shp"

BigBuffer = geopandas.read_file(Extent_path)
temp = os.path.split(Extent_path)
save_name_plot = temp[1].split('Buffer.')[0]
os.mkdir('D:/Random/Point/' + save_name_plot)

for shape_file in glob.glob(Centroid_path + '/*.shp'):
    split_path = os.path.split(shape_file)
    save_name = split_path[1].split('.')[0]
    Centroid = geopandas.read_file(shape_file)

    try:
        Clipped = geopandas.clip(BigBuffer, Centroid)
        Clipped.to_file('D:/Random/Point/' + save_name_plot + '/' + str(save_name) + '.shp')
    except:
        print()
```

**Edit 1 (removed `try except block`)**

```
...

for shape_file in glob.glob(Centroid_path + '/*.shp'):
    split_path = os.path.split(shape_file)
    save_name = split_path[1].split('.')[0]
    Centroid = geopandas.read_file(shape_file)

    Clipped = geopandas.clip(BigBuffer, Centroid)
    Clipped.to_file('D:/Random/Point/' + save_name_plot + '/' + str(save_name) + '.shp')
    print()
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Random/Model_Points_In_Plots.py", line 27, in <module>
    Clipped.to_file('D:/Random/Point/' + save_name_plot + '/' + str(save_name) + '.shp')
  File "C:\Users\z\anaconda3\envs\random\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py", line 1086, in to_file
    _to_file(self, filename, driver, schema, index, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\z\anaconda3\envs\random\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py", line 330, in _to_file
    colxn.writerecords(df.iterfeatures())
  File "C:\Users\z\anaconda3\envs\random\lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py", line 361, in writerecords
    self.session.writerecs(records, self)
  File "fiona/ogrext.pyx", line 1295, in fiona.ogrext.WritingSession.writerecs
RuntimeError: GDAL Error: Attempt to write non-multipoint (POINT) geometry to multipoint shapefile. 
 
 Failed to write record: {'id': '1', 'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'bottom': 5512954.238399999, 'id': 1, 'left': -13724655.3911, 'right': -13724198.191100001, 'top': 5513411.438399999}, 'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (-13724451.69110714, 5513680.37091026)}}
```

I printed out the centroid and buffer. Centroid is a `Multipoint` and Buffer is a `Polygon`. Not sure why it says it can't write a non-multipoint (POINT) to multipoint when my points are multipoints.

**Edit 2 (multipart to singlepart)**
I found a similar problem from another post [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/329580/point-sampling-tool-output-empty). I used QGIS's `multipart to singlepart` tool and tried again. This time it resulted in the same error, but did happen to write the first two (similar to purple points in picture one).

Comment: I looked through the documentation and tried multiple solutions, but have come up with two results. One being the saved output is the BigBuffer and the other is the Centroid. `geopandas.sjoin(Centroid, BigBuffer, how="left", op="contains")`

Comment: I am not verifying if the centroids land within the Buffer. I actually have another buffer layer within the main buffer layer that will be used. For this question, I am just after the clipped shapefile.

Comment: The files you are sharing are not the ones in your screenshot

Comment: Start by removing the try/except which is silencing any useful exceptions

Comment: Check to make sure your feature geometries are consistent. Mixed multi-parts can cause issues. You may also wish to test behaviour when no points fall within the buffer.

Comment: @BERA you are correct. Give me a couple minutes and I will fix that.

Comment: @mikewatt Okay I will test that out soon!

Comment: @CreekGeek I'll give that a look in a moment. For now I do not want the points that fall outside of the buffer. I actually have another buffer layer (did not post) that will be used with another clipping function. Those I will want both the points that fall within and outside.

Comment: @BERA The `Buffer` link now will give you the correct shapefile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically your issue is this one guy here:

[image]

This centroid only has one point in it so it gets assigned as POINT and not MULTIPOINT like the others. To fix this you can cast everything to MULTIPOINT like this:

```
# Needs to be added to imports:
from shapely.geometry import Point, MultiPoint

clipped = geopandas.clip(BigBuffer, Centroid, keep_geom_type=True)
clipped["geometry"] = [MultiPoint([feature]) if type(feature) == Point \
                        else feature for feature in clipped["geometry"]]
clipped.to_file('Downloads/test/' + save_name_plot + '/' + str(save_name) + '.shp')
```

Comment: Wow! Honestly, I don't think I would have ever figured that out. SUPER appreciate finding that issue! I'll be able to award the bounty when the time required has passed.